# How to log all input (cin) into file in C++

Tags: c++, shell, io

Actually, I'm working on a minishell. My functions work, but when I want to log the whole `cin` stuff (commands, parameters, output) into a file, nothing appears in the file. Nowhere can I find something to handle with full input and output with parameters.

I hope someone can help me.

My code:

```
using namespace std;

 ofstream outputFile;

void read_command(char *com, char **par){

    fprintf(stdout, "$");
    cin >> com;
    outputFile.open("logging.txt");     // file opened but nothing APPEARS IN IT????

        if(strcmp(com,"date")== 0){             // DATE
          time_t rawtime;
          time ( &rawtime );
          printf ( "%s", ctime (&rawtime) );
         }


        else if(strcmp(com,"echo")== 0)         // ECHO
        {
            string echo_part;
            cin >> echo_part;
            cout << echo_part << endl;

       }

        else if(strcmp(com,"sleep")== 0){           // SLEEP
            int howlong = 0;
            cin >> howlong;
            cout << "seconds: " << howlong << "....zZZzzZzz" << endl;
            sleep(howlong);

        }

        else if(strcmp(com,"ps")== 0)           // PROCESS
        {
            execlp("/bin/ps","ps","-A",NULL);       // ps  - command

        }

}

void handler(int p) {  // CTR-C handler

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Bye !" << endl;
    outputFile.close();
    alarm(1); // 2 seconds alarm ends process with kill
}


int main(){

    int childPid;
    int status;
    char command[20];
    char *parameters[60];
    signal(SIGINT,&handler); // CTR-C exit disabled



    while (1) {

      read_command(command, parameters);

        if ((childPid = fork()) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"can't fork\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (childPid == 0) { //child
            execv(command, parameters);
            exit(0);
        }
        else { // parent process
            wait(&status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but ever mix C++ standard iostreams (`cin`/`cout`) with the old C streams (`stdin`/`stdout`).

Answer (score 1):

You re-open the output stream outputFile for every line, overwriting the file with each new command.

Edit: As the other posters noted, not actually writing something to outputFile might be a second reason.

Answer (score 0):

You open `outputFile`, but never write anything to it. What should appear there?

To output something to the file, try

```
outputFile << something
```

Answer (score 0):

there are no

```
outputFile << ...;
```

so you are not writing to the file

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a lot of potential memory access violations.

There are libraries to help you in what you are trying to do (reading and interpreting user input), for instance the [GNU Readline library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), which is coded in C (but can be used by C++ code, as is the case for all the C-written libraries).
There are some nice C++ wrappers, such as for instance [SReadlineWrapper](http://satsky.spb.ru/codestore/SReadlineWrapperEng.php).